# C++ struct or array sorting

Tags: c++

Hello i have structure sorting function and now i am just wondering is there are easier way do this :

```
void Sorting(Sheeps v[],int all){

    for(int a =0; a < all; a++){
        for(int b = a+1; b < all; b++){
            if(v[b].dna_mach_rate > v[a].dna_mach_rate){
                v[4].dna_mach_rate = v[a].dna_mach_rate;
                v[a].dna_mach_rate = v[b].dna_mach_rate;
                v[b].dna_mach_rate = v[4].dna_mach_rate;
            }
        }
    }
    v[4].dna_mach_rate = 0;
}
```

so this function just run trough structure and replace values if from biggest to smallest , but this is kind a lot of code to do this , so i am wondering if there are functions like "php" or "javascript" ,"ushort" or something similar or the better way to sort array or structure 
this is how i was doing in "javascript" :

```
arrayname.sort(function(a, b){return b.speed - a.speed});
```

and almost same in php so i am wondering if there are similar or even better way to sort array or structure in c++

Comment: Do you mean `sort`?

Comment: yes sorr will edit

Comment: [std::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) perhaps

Comment: Do you want something that sorts properly, or something that's equivalent to what you posted? You're clobbering `v[4]`, sorting doesn't do that.

Comment: i was asking the best and easiest way to sort , cuz the code i post above its not the best solution i ges

Comment: Is there anything in the structure other than `dna_mach_rate`?  All you did was move the `dna_mach_rate` around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::sort(v, v+all, [](Sheeps const& lhs, Sheeps const& rhs){
  return lhs.dna_mach_rate < rhs.dna_mach_rate;
});
```

is sorting in C++ that takes the array `v` of length `all` and puts them in order so that the lowest `dna_mach_rate` goes first.

You need to `#include <algorithm>` first, naturally.  This also uses C++11 features, but C++11 is 5 years old at this point.

Comment: But the poster is not swapping the rest of the structure

Comment: @yahoo5000 [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2cc74a63859b11d) - I have no idea what compiler jsfiddle uses for C++ code.